# Auto insert date in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Is it possible to automatically add a date to a entry in the bibliographies after inserting the reference?

```
@misc{SOLID,
    author    = "Samuel Oloruntoba",
    title     = "S.O.L.I.D: The First 5 Principles of Object Oriented Design",
    url       = "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design"
    % date this entry was added to LaTex here?
}
```

Comment: Is something stopping you from entering a `date` or `year` field?

Comment: Incidentally, if the letters `S.O.L.I.D` in the `title` field are supposed to be rendered in uppercase, it's a good idea to encase the letters in an extra pair of curly braces: `{S.O.L.I.D}`.

Answer (score 1):

JabRef optionally can include a `timestamp` field  automatically:

```
@Article{,
  timestamp = {2020-12-15},
}
```

And optionally that timestamp can be updated if the entry is modified. The format of the date is configurable.